# Static import in javafx application returns ‘null ‘ with standard javafx:run command but works in debug mode and in artefact

Tags: java, maven, javafx, visual-studio-code

I recently ported a non-maven javafx application built in IntelliJ to a Maven application in VSCode (JDK14), partly to upgrade my code and partly to get more experience working with VSCode.

My Main class declares a static import:

```
public class Main extends Application {

static Stage theMainStage;
final Class<?> cls = this.getClass();
final ClassLoader cLoader = cls.getClassLoader();

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Application.launch(Main.class, (java.lang.String[]) null);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage PrimaryStage) {
    /*
    handle to the primary stage use as reference for other
    parts of application*/
    theMainStage = PrimaryStage;  //more code here..................
```

The main stage is reloaded by a call to the MainReloader class elsewhere in the program:

```
 //at head of class:
import static WeightingMachine.Main.theMainStage;  


public void Load() throws IOException {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        BorderPane bp = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("UI_HE2.fxml").openStream());
        chordController cC = fxmlLoader.getController();
        cC.setSingleEditState(se);
        cC.setInsertModeState(ins);

        //clear coordinate fields if in single edit mode:
        if ((se) || (ins)) {
            Collection<Node> collNodes = cC.chGridPane.getChildren();
            for (Node n : collNodes) {
                if (n.getId() != null && n.getId().contains("Num")) {
                    ((TextField) n).clear();
                }
            }
        }

        //set GUIto fit screen (need this to ensure interface is scrollable:
        Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, screenBounds.getWidth(), screenBounds.getHeight());
        scene.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        theMainStage.setScene(scene);
        theMainStage.show();

    } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
        Alert locAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        locAlert.setHeaderText("No resource found!");
        locAlert.setContentText("The program was unable to locate an FXML resource. " +
                "Try restarting the program and logging in to the database required.");
    }
}
```

The pox.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>HE.groupID</groupId>
  <artifactId>HE-archetypeID</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>HE-archetypeID</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
    <javafx.version>14.0.1</javafx.version>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
          <version>5.4.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
          <version>5.4.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>2.23.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>15-ea+5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>15-ea+5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ops4j.base</groupId>
      <artifactId>ops4j-base-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging dependencies -->
    <!-- first include logging api: -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Choose ONE! logging provider: -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0-alpha5</version>
  </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Include plugin so generated artifact can identify main class --> 
        <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>14</source>
                        <target>14</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
              <archive>
                  <index>true</index>
                  <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    <mainClass>WeightingMachine.Main</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
              </archive>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Include a helper plugin to assist with source management and 
        build config: Note the structure of this!-->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>add-source</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <!-- Include paths to source pacakges: -->
                      <sources>
                          <source>src/main/java/Login</source>
                          <source>src/main/java/Convolution</source>
                          <source>src/main/java/WeightingMachine</source>
                      </sources>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>copy-dependencies</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <!-- This, together with the Maven-jar-pluin is responsible for building an artifact
          Make sure the main class in stated
          the mojo to generate the artifcat is: mvn compile assembly:single -->
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>WeightingMachine.Main</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>      
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id> 
              <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
              <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>0.0.4</version>
              <configuration>
                  <mainClass>src/main/java/WeightingMachine/Main.java</mainClass>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

The StackTrace is as follows:

```
Main Stage from ChordController in initialization: null
Main Stage from ChordController before call: null
Main Stage from ChordController in initialization: null
12:42:06.382 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG WeightingMachine.chordController - before MainStage
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at WeightingMachine.MainReloader.Load(MainReloader.java:82)
        at WeightingMachine.chordController.lambda$addPitches$9(chordController.java:530)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8885)
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3890)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1885)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2618)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at WeightingMachine.chordController.lambda$addPitches$9(chordController.java:533)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8885)
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
        at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3890)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1885)
        at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2618)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at WeightingMachine.MainReloader.Load(MainReloader.java:82)
        at WeightingMachine.chordController.lambda$addPitches$9(chordController.java:530)
        ... 51 more
```

All works fine in the non-maven build in IntelliJ - without the pom obviously. Oddly, it works in the VSCode Maven build in *debug mode* where on stepping through 'theMainStage' is returned in the calling class as expected. Infuriatingly, The artifact built using the *mvn compile assembly:single* command also works OK.

In contrast, running the code in VSCode using the *mvn clean javafx:run* command returns 'theMainStage' as a null object within the calling class (and elsewhere in the project). There appears to be something odd happening that occurs only in the case of a standard run of the code where the static import declaration of 'theMainStage' in the Main class fails. I wonder whether anybody has any ideas what might be going on?  Thx in advance...

Comment: Are you sure that's the cause of the problem: is `theMainStage.setScene(...)` the actual line throwing the exception? Post the complete stack trace in the question.  Possibly related: your `catch(IllegalStateException)` will not catch an exception caused by the FXML not being found: that would cause a `NullPointerException` instead.

Comment: I'm as sure as I can be that the trouble spot is as indicated in the MainReloader class and that the problem is that javafx:run is not registering the original static import in the Main class.

Comment: You're missing the first line of the stack trace (the one that actually says what the exception is). Which line is line 82? If the `import` somehow wasn't working (which doesn't really make sense), you'd just get a compile error. Imports are resolved at compile time, so your code would behave exactly the sample way if you omitted the import and just replaced `theMainStage.setScene(...)` with `WeightingMachine.Main.theMainStage.setScene(...)`.

Comment: The head of the stack trace is there now :)

Comment: Line 82 is:     theMainStage.setScene(scene);   I know ,it shouldnt compile at all but it does for debug and for assembly.

Comment: @James_D Putting a println statement immediately before line 82: 'theMainStage.setScene(scene)'  gives the following in the case of javafx:run.: 'Main Stage from MainReloader in initialization: null'; whilst in the case of the built artefact and debug the same statement returns 'Main Stage from MainReloader in initialization: javafx.stage.Stage@70bc6fdb' which clearly shows the Main Stage object present and correct. I'm beginning to suspect a bug within the code for javafx:run

Comment: That's weird, and I can't explain it. However, sharing mutable data like this via `public static` fields is generally a very bad idea (I've never even seen, with the possible exception of `System.out`, anyone using static imports for mutable fields). Typically you can just get the current stage from a node in the scene: this looks like it is a controller class of some kind, so you likely have a reference to something in the scene graph anyway (or at a minimum you can get it from the event).

Comment: For anyone interested facing similar problems the javafx-maven-plugin paths in the pom.xml should be in dot notation NOT:
'src/main/java/WeightingMachine/Main.java' BUT JUST: 'WeightingMachine.Main'. This solved the above issue